# How do i configure Cucumber with TestNG? (Java) (Selenium)

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, testng

I'm completely new to the world of coding and automation and I don't have a great idea of what I'm doing, this is also my first post since I'm desperate in finding an answer and the other answers on the net didn't help me.

so I have all the dependencies added and I have all the requirements to integrate it, so how do I configure TestNG with Cucumber, a step by step explanation would be very helpful.

I tried making a runner class but I don't know where to go from here

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
     features = "src/test/Feature"
     ,glue={"src/main/stepDefinition"}
     )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/testng

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out why you need `Cucumber with TestNG`.

Is the current framework in `TestNG` and you are trying to integrate `BDD` with it?

If No, you could very well do it just with `Junit`.

If you would like to run with `TestNG`, you need to point your `testng.xml` file to run the cucumber runner class from it .
You can check [cucumber testing](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/automation-testing-with-selenium-cucumber-testng/) for reference.

Comment: My framework is in cucumber and I would like to integrate TestNG with it